# Setting the body background relative to entire page instead of viewport

Tags: html, css

I've been dealing with a problem for a day now, and I seem not to be able to solve it. I've got four images I want to use as CSS background on the `<body>` tag. They are supposed to be aligned as the corners of the page.

According to multiple resources I should set the `min-height` on both the `html` and `body` element to 100% if I want the placement my CSS background to be relative to the entire content of my page (which extends beneath the viewport) and not just to the viewport. However, this is not working. The bottom two corner images seem to be stuck to the bottom of the viewport.

I'm using this for CSS:

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: url(../images/bgTopLeft.png) no-repeat left top, 
                url(../images/bgTopRight.png) no-repeat right top,
                url(../images/bgBottomLeft.png) no-repeat left bottom,
                url(../images/bgBottomRight.png) no-repeat right bottom;
}
```

My HTML shouldn't matter much here as I'm using the `<body>` tag, can't do much wrong there. The doctype is HTML5 in case anyone wants to know.

I've tried changing the setting of `background-attachment` to `fixed`, I tried the various settings of `background-origin` even though it doesn't seem to have to do anything with my current problem. I tried breaking up the multiple shorthand `background` into all the separate statements that are in there. I can't get it to work.

I'd rather not resort to sticking the bottom two corner images into a footer or a div at the bottom of my page that's just there for styling purposes. What I want, which is a `<body>` tag with four backgrounds positioned in the four corners of the entire page, should be possible, I just can't figure out what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a pen of what I think you're trying to achieve here:

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/swervo/pen/zKtHj)

I've used background-size to size the background images.
You may need to tweak this to match the size of your background images:

eg:

`background-size: 40px 40px, 40px 40px, 40px 50px, 60px 60px;`

depending on what size your images are.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to you. I've been moving the past two weeks. I've tried setting `background-size` but it doesn't change anything, except for the size of my images. Any other pointers?

Comment: Does the Codepen example here:

http://codepen.io/swervo/pen/zKtHj

match what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Admittedly, it does appear to be identical to your code - but it seems to work as you described. Images in the corners of the body, not the viewport.